# Fetch parent categories that have no sub_category or children in osCommerce

Tags: mysql, sql, oscommerce

In my osCommerce store I want to fetch the parent_id of categories that either have no sub category or child categories.

I used the following in my code:

```
$categories_query = tep_db_query("select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name 
    from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd 
    where c.parent_id = '$parent_id' and 
    c.categories_id = cd.categories_id 
    order by sort_order, cd.categories_name");
```

The above translates into this when the constants are filled in:

```
select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name 
    from categories c, categories_description cd 
    where c.parent_id = '$parent_id' and 
    c.categories_id = cd.categories_id 
    order by sort_order, cd.categories_name
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It is helpful if you can simplify your code, as I have done in your edit. It's especially useful if you can untangle your PHP and SQL code when asking SQL questions.

Comment: pleasee help me. if you want to more elaboration from me then please tell me. i am trying to understand my problem. but please troubleshoot out my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this:

```
SELECT c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id 
  FROM categories c, categories_description cd 
  WHERE c.categories_id=cd.categories_id 
  AND c.categories_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT c2.parent_id FROM categories c2)
  ORDER BY c.sort_order, cd.categories_name
```

or you can go with that:

```
SELECT c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id 
  FROM categories c 
  LEFT JOIN categories_description cd 
  ON c.categories_id=cd.categories_id
  WHERE c.categories_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT c2.parent_id FROM categories c2)
  ORDER BY c.sort_order, cd.categories_name
```

But what you really want to know about is this line:

```
  c.categories_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT c2.parent_id FROM categories c2)
```

Since the `parent_id` column is in the same table as [the one you're looking up and not in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752776/select-parent-row-only-if-it-has-no-children) you'll need to look up the table on itself and reference it via another alias.

This part of the SQL will return all the `categories_id` (actually `parents_id` in the table) that are being referenced as parent categories:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c2.parent_id FROM categories c2
```

Now, when you put that into a [`NOT IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in) comparison you're left with rows that do not have any children categories underneath.

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing your table layouts, there's some guessing needed to answer your question.  But, I believe you need a query like this:

```
     SELECT c.parent_id
       FROM TABLE_CATEGORIES c
  LEFT JOIN TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION cd ON c.categories_id = cd.categories_id
      WHERE cd.categories_id IS NULL
```

Note that this `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL` pattern matches the rows in the first table joined that don't have a match in the second table.

Comment: The categories and categories_description tables are linked by the categories_id column since the latter is where all the name and description info is. But your query shows the rows where it doesn't have a row.

Comment: my table layout is similar to os commerce table layout. i want to fetch those parent_id which has no child.